# Definition of Jet bundle

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, differential-topology

I was learning differential topology, here is one of the definitions of Jet bundle on the book :Stable Mappings and Their Singularities by M.Golubitsky & V. Guillemin,as follows:

**Definition 2.1.** Let $X$ and $Y$ be smooth manifolds, and $p$ in $X$. Suppose $f, g: X \rightarrow Y$ are smooth maps with $f(p)=g(p)=q$.

(1) $f$ has first order contact with $g$ at $p$ if $(d f)_{p}=(d g)_{p}$ as mapping of $T_{p} X \rightarrow T_{q} Y$

(2) $f$ has $k$ th order contact with $g$ at $p$ if $(d f): T X \rightarrow T Y$ has $(k-1) s t$ order contact with $(dg)$ at every point in $T_{p} X .$ This is written as $f \sim_{k} g$ at $p .$ ( $k$ is a positive integer.)

What I don't understand is the $k\ge 2$ order case(say for example $k =2$),since by definition it means $df$  has first order contact with $dg$ at $p$,which means by (1) $(ddf)_p = (ddg)_p$ but we know $d^2 = 0$ why can we do like this?

Comment: $d$ here denotes the differential, not the exterior derivative.

Comment: thank you ,do you mean ,for example the second order case is in terms of Hessian?Do we need Riemannian metric here? @Kajelad

Comment: No; you don't need a metric or a notion of a Hessian, just the definition of the differential. $df:TX\to TY$ is a smooth map, so it makes sense to take its differential $d(df):T(TX)\to T(TY)$ and so on. It might be instructive to see what this definition looks like in local coordinates.

Comment: I see thank you,under the coordinate if we take $TX$ has coordinate $(x_1,...,x_n)$ and $TY$ has coordinate $(y_1,..,y_m)$ then  $d(df)(v_i \frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}) \mapsto v_i \frac{\partial (df)^j}{\partial x^i}\frac{\partial}{\partial y_j}$

Comment: That's true, but not particularly useful. The idea I as alluding to is that choosing coordinates on $X$ and $Y$ induces adapted coordinates on $TX$ and $TY$, and in these coordinates it becomes possible to express $d(df)$ etc. in terms of the partial derivatives of $f$.